# firefox extension:- pagemod not working

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I wanted to modify the web page, every time the top page (not the iframes within page) is loaded. To my estimate I would need to use page-mod. But in my case it is not working.

1) Created file "lib/main.js" with following content

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
include: "*",
contentScriptWhen: 'end',
attachTo: ["top",  "existing"],
contentScript: 'window.alert("Page matches ruleset");'
});
```

2) created another file "install.rdf" with following content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">
  <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
    <em:id>{a2a7da09-1be1-4e24-8324-5560048a3ead}</em:id>
    <em:name>Demo</em:name>
    <em:version>1.0.0</em:version>
    <em:description>Demo for Firefox</em:description>
    <em:type>2</em:type>
    <em:creator>sam</em:creator>
    <em:targetApplication>
      <!-- Firefox -->
      <Description>
        <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
        <em:minVersion>3.0</em:minVersion>
        <em:maxVersion>24.0</em:maxVersion>
      </Description>
    </em:targetApplication>
    <em:targetApplication>      
      <!-- SeaMonkey -->
      <Description>
        <em:id>{92650c4d-4b8e-4d2a-b7eb-24ecf4f6b63a}</em:id>
        <em:minVersion>2.0</em:minVersion>
        <em:maxVersion>2.21</em:maxVersion>
      </Description>      
    </em:targetApplication>
  </Description>
</RDF>
```

Some body tell me what wrong am i doing.
If possible please provide any basic working sample.

Thanks all

Comment: Do you have any errors or anything? If you are using the Add-on SDK you should not need to create your own install.rdf, this is created for you when you run cfx xpi to create the xpi file. When in doubt, please follow the intro and tutorials provided here in the SDK's docs: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/

Comment: @canuckistani thanks. Your Comment helped my extension started working. Now there is last issue. How do I refer to image with extension?

Comment: Any images in the data folder can be referred to from scripts / css / html in the same data folder via relative paths.

Comment: Done with that. I also wanted to inject Iframe. Though it is being injected and is loading URI from internet, but fails to to load uri from within the extension locally.

Comment: That's a known bug, the iframe can't load from data due to platform security restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

- the OP just needed to use the `cfx` tool as [shown in the tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_started) to get things working